# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'stickyPanel'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
sticky_contentActions: function() {
        $("#content_actions").stickyPanel({
            topPadding: 0,
            afterDetachCSSClass: "sticky_actions",
            savePanelSpace: false
        }); 
    }
```

i have this method stickyPanel in my library. when i reload the page it seems to work correctly but when i click the link again iam getting this error in ie

Comment: We will need more details than this. Could you show the click handler?

Comment: The specific error is because your `stickyPanel` JQuery extension is missing at the time the code shown is called. You may have failed to initialise correctly, or any of a dozen other simple problems that occur elsewhere in your code. You will need to show more code.

Comment: plalx.. the link is in a href which loads a new jsp page

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie when my jsp is called it calls the above method which inturn calls stickypanel. when i reload the page it works fine but when i click the link again it doesnt go to stickyPanel js. this works fine in firefox.only in ie this is an issue

Comment: ##fixed- 
 the js file was called under header of jsp page

<script type="text/javascript">
  head.js("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/...../js/jquery.stickyPanel.js");
</script>

i moved it like this below

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/.../js/jquery.stickyPanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

now it works fine.. :)